# How do I keep objects that meet a specific criteria in a vector, and move them out otherwise?

Tags: c++, vector

I am making a 2D game in SDL2 with C++. I have made some simple terrain generation so that you can walk on an endless amount of world tiles. Right now I iterate through all of the tiles that resembles the world, check if the current one is on the screen and then render it. But since I am iterating through all of them this might get slow if you explore alot. And when I add enemies I don't want to iterate through all of them either.

This is why I want to have one vector containing all the tiles that are visible (on the screen) and one with all the tiles. This might seem useless since I will still probably need to iterate through all of the tiles one time, but I want to do it like this because some functions can then more easily be kept to the tiles on the screen.

So how do I have a vector full of objects that meet a certain criteria, and only then?

This is something I have right now that resembles the part where I tried to solve this problem. It uses pointers to check whether the element is in the list of visible tiles (a vector of pointers), but with this method I have problems checking conditions on them later.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); ++i) {
    tiles[i].update(camera_x, camera_y);
    if (tiles[i].onScreenX(winW, winH, 100)) {
        if (tiles[i].onScreen == false) {
            tiles[i].onScreen = true;
            tilesOnScreen.push_back(&tiles[i]);
        }
    }
    else if (tiles[i].onScreen == true) {
        for (int o = 0; o < tilesOnScreen.size(); ++o) {
            if (&tiles[i] == tilesOnScreen[o]) {
                tiles[i].onScreen = false;
                tilesOnScreen.erase(tilesOnScreen.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you store your tiles in a 2D array, iterating only over the visible tiles becomes trivial.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have actually not had problems becuase the size gets to large, but that might be since the tiles are pretty big and therefor few.

Comment: if you're using c++ 20 i'd use a view

Comment: [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) or `std::stable_partition` would partition the tiles on screen with the one's off the screen.

Comment: Similar to HolyBlackCat's idea: `std:(unordered_)map<Coords, Tile>` could be another way to access certain elements without looping over everything. You could just loop over `Coords` from one corner to the opposite one for visible tiles. Maybe combined with a visitor pattern - a function that receives a functor and evaluates it with all the "visible" tiles. There's a lot to consider, and each solution comes with its own tradeoff.